# Java symbol not found

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

I am trying to compiling 2 files this is my main GUI file

```
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;



public class testP3 extends JFrame implements testP3FieldEdit
{
    private JTextField F_Name_text;
    private JTextField L_Name_text;
    private JTextArea textarea;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testP3 gui = new testP3();
        gui.setVisible(true);
     }
     public testP3()
    {
        super("testPro3");


        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(650,600);
        JPanel mainP = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel yoloP = new JPanel();
        JPanel buttP=new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel statusbar = new JPanel();
        JPanel statusP =new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        statusbar.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
        JLabel stdunt = new JLabel("Student Id:");


        JLabel F_Name_label = new JLabel("F_Name");
        F_Name_text = new JTextField(40);
        yoloP.add(F_Name_label);
        yoloP.add(F_Name_text);
        JLabel L_Name_label = new JLabel("L_Name");
        L_Name_text = new JTextField(40);
        yoloP.add(L_Name_label);
        yoloP.add(L_Name_text);


        JButton Add_button = new JButton("Add");
        buttP.add(Add_button);
        JButton Clean_button = new JButton("Clean");
        buttP.add(Clean_button);
        JButton Submit_button = new JButton("Submit");
        buttP.add(Submit_button);
            textarea = new JTextArea(20,40);
        textarea.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textarea);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);


        yoloP.setLayout(new BoxLayout(yoloP,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));


        mainP.add(yoloP);
        mainP.add(buttP);


        statusbar.setLayout(new BoxLayout(statusbar,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JLabel  statusLabel = new JLabel();


        statusLabel.setText("status");
        statusbar.add(statusLabel);
        statusbar.add(scroll);
        mainP.add(statusbar);
        add(mainP);
    }
    public String getDCF_Name()
    {
             return(F_Name_text.getText());
    }
    public void setDCF_Name(String F_Name)
    {
            F_Name_text.setText(F_Name);
    }
    public String getDCL_Name()
    {
             return(L_Name_text.getText());
    }
    public void setDCL_Name(String L_Name)
    {
            L_Name_text.setText(L_Name);
    }
    public void appendToStatusArea(String message)
    {
        textarea.append(message + "\n");
    }
}
```

Which has an interface implemented on this file

```
public interface testP3FieldEdit
{
        public String getDCF_Name();
        public void setDCF_Name(String F_Name);
        public String getDCL_Name();
        public void setDCL_Name(String L_Name);
        public void appendToStatusArea(String message);
}
```

and I was wondering why it cannot find the symbol, and both file are in the same folder

```
symbol: class testP3FieldEdit
public class testP3 extends JFrame implements testP3FieldEdit
                                              ^
1 error
```

Comment: How do you compile your classes.

Comment: Is either source in a `package`?

Comment: There not in a package and there both in a folder called testP3

 i am compiling like this javac ./testP3/testP3.java, If i go inside the folder testP3 and compile like javac testP3.java then it works fine, but it dont work the other way

Comment: *"If i go inside the folder testP3 and compile like javac testP3.java then it works fine, but it dont work the other way"*  This is relevant information.  *Add it into the question as an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28930288/edit).*

Comment: `javac ./testP3/testP3.java`  Should be something like `javac -sourcepath testP3 *.java`  Consult the [javac options documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCGAJDC) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine with me. I assume that you're compiling using javac in which case you have to compile both files at the same time or compile `testP3FieldEdit` first.
Move to the directory of both files and compile it this way

```
javac testP3.java testP3FieldEdit.java
```